# Does Google Analytics show past AdWords data?

Tags: google-analytics, google-ads

I just linked an AdWords account to a Google Analytics view. When I go to "Acquisition -> AdWords -> Campaigns" there is no data at all. No campaigns, no ad groups, nothing. Am I supposed to wait a day to see something in Google Analytics or is it supposed to show something instantly?

Comment: it's okay to reply to your own question if you've got the answer! Just make it clear what the issue was and then separately what the resolution was.

Comment: And, if you don't make the question and answer clear as @Yhorian said, just remove the question altogether.

Comment: Thank you guys. I'm not that familiar with using StackExchange. I added my answer to the question. I'll leave this question up if anyone else comes across the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. Apparently it took a few hours (?) for the data to go over from AdWords to Analytics. Now I can see my campaign and its data.